# Does 2-3% GPU usage 24/7 on the wear it?

Tags: windows-10, gpu, nvidia-rtx

Does the 2-3% GPU usage all the time wear the gpu?
or it is the same as it being on 0%?
On Windows 10

Or if different cards act differently, im talking about RTX card

Comment: 2-3% GPU utilization will cause very little additional stress (power consumption, heat generation) on the components compared to running the GPU at idle (0%). Don’t worry about it.

Comment: aight, thanks dud